# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded caused by post ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have script like this

```
function on_save() {

var departemen_id = $('#departemen_id').val(), departemen_name = $('#departemen_name').val(), no = $('#no').val();


$.post('<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/departemen/update', { deptartemen_ID : departemen_id, departemen_name : dept_name }, function(data){
//my script here
}, 'json');
```

}

In my Departemen Controller only like this because I just want to know I was writing right url.

```
public function actionUpdate()
{
   $array = array('result'=>'failed');
   echo json_encode($array);
   exit();
}
```

My browser give me this on console

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I already serached its error by commenting line by line, and I only get something wrong in post function. 
Can sameone help me?
Thanks

Comment: where do you bind your click handler for the save function? By the way `departemen_ID`in post should be `departemen_id` ?

Comment: I already update it. 
you mean my button? I already check it with print some words in console if the button clicked, and it is working well.

Answer (score 0):

This `departemen_name : dept_name` should be like this: `dept_name : departemen_name`, because `departemen_name` is the value you just retrieved from the `dom` and want to assign to property `dept_name`.